# Ord instance comparing tree height freezes with >= or >

Tags: haskell

It is not possible to compare trees in height with signs greater than `(>)` and greater than or equal to `(>=)`. Here is my code. It just freezes at the command `tree1 >= tree2`:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving (Eq,Show)
instance (Ord a) => Ord (Tree a) where
    Node a list1 >= Node b list2 = (list1 > list2) || (list1 == list2)
    (Node a list1) > (Node b list2) = (list1 > list2)

t0 = Node 15 []
t1 = Node 15 []
t2 = Node 120 [t0]
tree1 = Node 130 [t1,t2]

tt0 = Node 155 []
tt1 = Node 112 [t2]
tt2 = Node 128 [t0]
tree2 = Node 110 [tt1,tt2,tt0]
```

Comment: You parenthesized the `Node` arguments to `>`, but not `>=`, in the definition of the `Ord` instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for the [`Ord` class](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-19.8/base-4.15.1.0/Prelude.html#t:Ord) includes a section on the "minimal definition":

> **Minimal complete definition**
>
> ```
> compare | (<=)
> ```

This means that you **must** define at least one of `compare` or `(<=)`.  Otherwise, there is a danger that the default definitions provided by the class will either crash or loop.

In addition, even though it's less clearly documented, it's important that the definitions of `Eq` and `Ord` be compatible.  If `tree3 <= tree4` and `tree3 >= tree4`, then you'd better have `tree3 == tree4`.  Your definition doesn't satisfy this, because your `Ord` instance ignores the contents of the nodes, but the automatically derived `Eq` instance will compare them.

You should instead write your own `Eq` instance and your own minimal `Ord` instance:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving (Show)
instance (Eq a) => Eq (Tree a) where
  Node _ list1 == Node _ list2 = list1 == list2
instance (Ord a) => Ord (Tree a) where
  Node _ list1 <= Node _ list2 = list1 <= list2
```

After this, all comparison operators should work correctly:

```
λ> compare tree1 tree2
LT
λ> tree1 == tree2
False
λ> tree1 < tree2
True
λ> tree1 <= tree2
True
λ> tree1 >= tree2
False
λ> tree1 > tree2
False
λ> tree1 == tree2
False
λ> tree1 /= tree2
True
```

FYI, the reason your original definition loops is a little obscure.  With your original incorrect definition:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving (Eq,Show)
instance (Ord a) => Ord (Tree a) where
  Node a list1 >= Node b list2 = (list1 > list2) || (list1 == list2)
  (Node a list1) > (Node b list2) = (list1 > list2)
```

you'll find that the following works:

```
> Node 1 [] >= Node 2 []
True
```

but the following hangs:

```
> [Node 1 []] >= [Node 2 []]
Interrupted.
```

The problem is that the definition of `Ord` for lists is defined in terms of `compare`, so even though it *looks* like your definition is only using `>=` and `>`, it's also using `compare` behind the scenes when it compares lists of child nodes.  Since the default definition of `compare` is defined in terms of `<=` and the default definition of `<=` is defined in terms of `compare`, you get a loop in the default definitions.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: define `<=`.

Enable warnings, it will say:

> - No explicit implementation for
>   either ‘compare’ or ‘<=’
> - In the instance declaration for ‘Ord (Tree a)’

For `Ord`, you must implement at least one of these: `<=` or `compare`.

This is due to the standard implementation for these two functions of `Ord` which is available on [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.8.0/docs/src/GHC.Classes.html#compare):

```
 compare x y = if x == y then EQ
                  -- NB: must be '<=' not '<' to validate the
                  -- above claim about the minimal things that
                  -- can be defined for an instance of Ord:
                  else if x <= y then LT
                  else GT
    x <  y = case compare x y of { LT -> True;  _ -> False }
   -- ...
   {-# MINIMAL compare | (<=) #-}
```

As you can see, these two functions are defined in terms of one another, so it will freeze / loop endlessly. And the minimal pragma is used for the warning and can be seen in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-Ord.html) as

> Minimal complete definition
>
> ```
> compare | (<=)
> ```